# Google Maps custom markers on ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, marker

I am using custom markers on Google Maps, and they work perfectly on browser mode, but the problem happens with device, I can't get picture of marker, not sure if I am placing image of marker right.

This is the code I am using.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
position: myLatLng,     
map:this.map,   
title: 'Pumpa',     
icon: {         url: "../assets/img/2.png",
scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30)    
} });
```

any clues where should I put marker image and what path should I use then.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the downvotes on the previous answer are about, using

```
url: "assets/img/2.png"
```

works for me

Answer (score -2):

i think you need to remove the 2 dots in url of icon

Comment: Are you sure? While it _could_ work, there aren’t any obvious clues in the question suggesting this _will_ solve the issue. In my opinion, these clarifications belong in the comments, not as separate answers.

Comment: icon: 'file:///android_asset/www/assets/markers/custom_icon.png'

This works for android. assets is standard ionic2 app dir, markers is custom subdir with icon files.